How to run multiple sql scripts in one button in Python Flask
I have a python flask web app and I want to add a button that does the following when clicked. Insert, update, then select.
I have the sql script in dbeaver working and am trying to essentially make a button that does the whole script. Using Postgresql BTW.
I have seen
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text('SELECT * FROM your_table'))

But seems like this isn't a button.

checkout sqlalchemy

Please provide a [mre] or show more research.  Generally the button would be part of an HTML form where the user is entering data.  That form would POST to a flask route that handles the SQL actions and then it may either do the Select you want to load to the page, or it might redirect to another route.

My first question would be are they scripts or stored procedures. If they are not procs I would make them into procs.
If all three are always going to be called together I would make it one proc. If not I would make three procs and a fourth one that you call that runs the other three.

They are stored procedures.
